# Replace the match itself, not the wild card, using awk gsub or generic regular expressions

Tags: regex, replace, awk, find, gsub

I have a tab-delimited file of the following appearance:

```
12-38070040-39070040    13-92416321-93446176    14-47539055-48560868     14-89244697-90244697   14-90046821-91047886    14-98556636-99556636    15-47718221-48718221
```

I want to replace all instances of:

tab, then any two digits, then a hyphen   \t[0-9][0-9]-

with:

tab, then the same two digits, then a colon     \t SAME TWO DIGITS :

```
12:38070040-39070040    13:92416321-93446176    14:47539055-48560868     14:89244697-90244697   14:90046821-91047886    14:98556636-99556636    15:47718221-48718221
```

How can I match using a wildcard, but then replace the match, instead of replacing the wildcard?

One last note, I have asked about `awk '{gsub()}'` because I use it the most, however if there is generic "pseudo regex" that would work in most environments, most text editors, etc., I would be just as happy to learn about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you're referring to is a capture group. Capture groups enable you to use part of the matched pattern in the replacement string.

Normal `gsub` doesn't allow you to use capture groups but if you're using GNU awk, you can use `gensub` instead:

```
awk '{print gensub(/\y([0-9][0-9])-/, "\\1:", "g")}' file
```

This captures the two digits preceded by a word boundary `\y` and followed by a hyphen. The digits are then used in the replacement (that's what the `\\1` is for), followed by a colon. The "g" argument means that a global substitution is performed. If multiple capture groups were specified, they would be `\\2`, `\\3` etc.

Testing it out on your file:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/\y([0-9][0-9])-/, "\\1:", "g")}' file
12:38070040-39070040    13:92416321-93446176    14:47539055-48560868     14:89244697-90244697   14:90046821-91047886    14:98556636-99556636    15:47718221-48718221
```

You can use sed to do the same job:

```
sed -r 's/(^|[[:space:]])([0-9]{2})-/\1\2:/g' file
```

This matches any two digits preceded by either a character in the space class (tabs and spaces are included) or the start of the line `^` and followed by a hyphen. Now there are two capture groups, so the replacement contains them both as well as the colon. Using BSD sed (e.g. on a Mac), use `-E` instead of `-r` to enable extended regex mode.

Since we're dealing with regexes, it seems unreasonable not to mention Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\b(\d{2})-/\1:/g' file
```

This uses the word boundary `\b` which matches the gap between the beginning of the number and either the start of the line or whitespace. `\d` is the digit class, a shorthand for `[0-9]`. The replacement is similar to the one use in awk, except that we don't need to escape the backslash.

Output in all cases:

```
12:38070040-39070040    13:92416321-93446176    14:47539055-48560868     14:89244697-90244697   14:90046821-91047886    14:98556636-99556636    15:47718221-48718221
```

Answer (score 4):

One awk and one sed solution are included here.  Let us start with the sed solution:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]{2})-/\1:/; s/\t([0-9]{2})-/\t\1:/g' file
12:38070040-39070040    13:92416321-93446176    14:47539055-48560868    14:89244697-90244697      14:90046821-91047886    14:98556636-99556636    15:47718221-48718221
```

This uses two sed commands:

- `s/^([0-9]{2})-/\1:/`

  If a line begins with two numbers followed by a dash, this matches and substitutes in the same numbers (`\1`) and a colon.
- `s/\t([0-9]{2})-/\t\1:/g`

  Anytime a tab is followed by two numbers and a dash, this substitutes in a tab, the same two numbers (`\1`), and a colon.

The `-r` option on GNU sed (`-E` on OSX) tells sed to use extended regex so that fewer backslashes are needed.

For Mac OSX and other non-GNU platforms, try:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/^([0-9]{2})-/\1:/' -e 's/\t([0-9]{2})-/\t\1:/g' file
```

#### Awk solution

If we restrict ourselves to standard parts of the awk language, then we lose the elegance of regexes but we can still assemble the right answer by using `substr`:

```
$ awk -v 'OFS=\t' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^[0-9][0-9]-/) {$i=substr($i,0,2)":"substr($i,4)}}} 1' file
12:38070040-39070040    13:92416321-93446176    14:47539055-48560868    14:89244697-90244697    14:90046821-91047886    14:98556636-99556636    15:47718221-48718221
```

Taking each part, a piece at a time:

- `-v 'OFS=\t'`

  This sets the output field separator to tab.
- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^[0-9][0-9]-/) {$i=substr($i,0,2)":"substr($i,4)}}}`

  This loops over every field and, if the field starts with two numbers followed by a dash, then a new value is assigned to the field consisting of the first two numbers followed by a colon followed by the rest of the field.
- `1`

  This is cryptic shorthand for print the whole line.